# can not use file_get_contents of dyanmically created location

Tags: php

I am trying to use file_get_contents() to get the html from a page.
the following works great: `file_get_contents('http://www.mypage.com?Title=Title')` but the following causes an error:

```
$Title = 'Title';
file_get_contents("http://www.mypage.com?Title=$Title")
```

The error is:

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
The request line contained invalid characters following the protocol string.

Apache/1.3.41 Server at eiit.org Port 80
```

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a string with single-quotes ; and there is no variable interpolation with single-quotes.

Which means the URL you're trying to fetch is `http://www.mypage.com?Title=$Title`, and not `http://www.mypage.com?Title=Title`.

You should use a double-quoted string, to have variable interpolation :

```
$Title = 'Title';
file_get_contents("http://www.mypage.com?Title=$Title");
```

If this still doesn't work :

- Check if your URL is OK : instead of directly passing it to `file_get_contents`, store it in a variable, and echo it -- just to be sure it's right.
- Why is there no page-name in your URL ?

  - You have the domain-name : `www.mypage.com`
  - And a parameter+value : `Title=Title`
  - But no file/page ? i.e., why don't you have something like `http://www.mypage.com/index.php?Title=$Title` ? Or even `http://www.mypage.com/?Title=$Title` ?
- You might have to [urlencode](http://php.net/urlencode) the values you're passing as parameters in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Variables inside single quotes dont get interpolated; try:

```
$Title = 'Title';
file_get_contents("http://www.mypage.com?Title=$Title")
```

Comment: oops I did use double quotes, that was a typo when I put it in here

Comment: Why don't you copy & paste your misbehaving code; who knows if you made any other typos :)

Comment: I prefer not to post actual code.  I like to anonymize it before I post it.

Comment: Pascals post is why you should copy &paste and then maybe change www.yourreal.url to www.example.com  doing things like $title='title'; don't let anyone see if you've made basic errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `http://www.mypage.com/?Title=$Title`? The slash after the domain name is the path - you must always have a path in an HTTP request.

Comment: not always true: put http://www.smarty.net?hello in your browser ... the slash gets rewritten in (by the webserver) but your request gets the site

Comment: @Erik : is it the webserver that adds the slash, or your browser ? Checking the HTTP request, it seems the browser sends a GET request that starts with a /, even if I didn't put it in the original URL -- which indicates the / is added by the browser, and not the server

Comment: Pascal is right. `GET  HTTP/1.1` is not a valid HTTP request. The browser converts it to `GET / HTTP/1.1`.

Answer (score 0):

if i don't if you have resolved your problem, but another way you can try. (although i don't think it matters)

```
$Title = 'Title';
$result=file_get_contents("http://www.mypage.com?Title=".$Title)
```